# Wire Service Question

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have a wire service that brings back a listing of records.  I also have a "New" button on the LWC which uses a child component with a record-edit-form.  I send an event that bubbles up to the parent after saving a new record and in the parent method I refresh apex.  This works fine unless there are no records and I am adding the first record.  The wire service does not get fired and the new record does not show up in my list until I refresh the page.  Any suggestions on making this work when I'm creating my first record?  thanks!!

Comment: Please provide some snippets with source code to clarify your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cheat that should work is by passing a reactive parameter to your wired method. Lets say, the method which is decorated by wire take a parameter number of records rendered

```js
export default class ReactiveWiredApexDemo extends LightningComponent {
  recordsRendered = 0;
  records;
  @wire(getRecords, { recordsRendering: '$recordsRendered' }
  getWiredRecords(response) {
    this.records = response;
    this.recordsRendered = response?.data?.length || 0;
  }

  handleRefresh(event) {
    // this will be called when child's event is received
    this.recordsRendered = 1 + this.recordsRendered;
  }
}
```

Because of the '$' symbol, every time the recordsRendered changes, getRecords will be called.